# Writing a large amount of UTF8 bytes to a file results in massive bloat

Tags: c#, utf-8, character-encoding, streamwriter

So I was recently playing around, and attempted to generate a 1GB file.

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\parsonsj\Desktop\data.dat");
Encoding utf8enc = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;

for (int i = 0; i < 1073741824; i++) {
    writer.Write(utf8enc.GetBytes("#"));
}
writer.Close();
```

My thoughts were that since UTF8 characters were 1 byte and 1GB is about 1,073,741,824 bytes, writing a single UTF8 character 1,073,741,824 times would result in an approximately 1GB file size.

I ran my little program and as expected, it started slowing things down and eating memory. I ended up prematurely killing it, and went to check the file size, curious how far I got. To my horror, the file was a whopping **13GB**.

I'm not sure how it got so big. Perhaps I'm encoding it wrong. Perhaps there was some sort of crazy memory-leak related bug. I'm just confused.

Why was my file so big? Am I misunderstanding the encoding or the math?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `utf8enc.GetBytes("#")`? It almost seems like you're expecting it to do something different from what it will do. But I'm not certain.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb encode the string as UTF8 before writing it to the file. Is that not what it does?

Comment: What I meant by what I asked is just that I don't think you're writing what you're intending. (hence dasblinkenlight's answer). Sorry, I didn't direct my question very  well...

Comment: Not that it's related to the question, but utf8 character can take up to 4 bytes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `writer.Write` does not have an overload for `byte[]` array. The compiler thinks that you are trying to call the overload taking `System.Object`, and so the array gets written to the stream as `"System.Byte[]"`.

Fix this by using `FileStream`'s [`Write(Byte\[\], int, int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.write(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: As advice to the OP, this would be very obvious had he opened the file in a hex editor.

Comment: @RonBeyer: But most editors are not so advanced to open a file of 13GB.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Most *hex* editors are capable of opening those files since they don't load the entire file into memory (or at all). You can't open it in notepad, but even free hex editors like HHD have no problem opening a file like that.